# MAAS on KVM - problem with PXE boot

Tags: juju, maas, kvm-virtualization

MAAS version: 2.3.0 (6434-gd354690-0ubuntu1~16.04.1)

Running on:

```
kurt@ZEUS-01:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Following the example provided in the tutorial:
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-kvm-pods-with-maas

Not that it matters, but my particular deployment configuration is on VMWare Fusion 10.1.1 on Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.3.

After believing I have set up everything to specification, I am unable to commission a node (it times out).  More specifically, PXE boot does not appear to be working.

I believe there is a problem in the networking or something around the virtual bridging that is causing PXE boot to grab an IP on the correct network.

Where does 192.168.231

[image]

Here are some things I've discovered in trying to figure out the problem:

There is no tun/vibr0 created (is this normal?)

```
kurt@ZEUS-01:~$ ifconfig -a
br1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:41:fa:67  
      inet addr:192.168.30.1  Bcast:192.168.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe41:fa67/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2101 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2426335 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:911243 (911.2 KB)

ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:41:fa:5d  
      inet addr:192.168.1.55  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe41:fa5d/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:303300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:646992 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:32317905 (32.3 MB)  TX bytes:1389193503 (1.3 GB)

ens34     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:41:fa:67  
      inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe41:fa67/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6003 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3069 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2504269 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:1232690 (1.2 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2299751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2299751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:4129641186 (4.1 GB)  TX bytes:4129641186 (4.1 GB)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:85:03:31  
      inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe85:331/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:1197 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7070 (7.0 KB)  TX bytes:12642 (12.6 KB)
```

Here are the summarized interface outputs from the web gui:
[image]

Here is the output of

Here is the bridge config:

```
kurt@ZEUS-01:~$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br1     8000.000c2941fa67   no      ens34
                                    vnet0
```

Here is the maas network dump

```
kurt@ZEUS-01:~$ sudo maas-rack support-dump --networking
### get_ip_addr() ###
{'br1': {'bridged_interfaces': ['ens34', 'vnet0'],
     'flags': ['BROADCAST', 'MULTICAST', 'UP', 'LOWER_UP'],
     'index': 4,
     'inet': ['192.168.30.1/24'],
     'mac': '00:0c:29:41:fa:67',
     'name': 'br1',
     'settings': {'group': 'default',
                  'mtu': '1500',
                  'qdisc': 'noqueue',
                  'qlen': '1000',
                  'state': 'UP'},
     'type': 'ethernet.bridge'},
'ens33': {'flags': ['BROADCAST', 'MULTICAST', 'UP', 'LOWER_UP'],
       'index': 2,
       'inet': ['192.168.1.55/24'],
       'mac': '00:0c:29:41:fa:5d',
       'name': 'ens33',
       'settings': {'group': 'default',
                    'mtu': '1500',
                    'qdisc': 'pfifo_fast',
                    'qlen': '1000',
                    'state': 'UP'},
       'type': 'ethernet.physical'},
'ens34': {'flags': ['BROADCAST', 'MULTICAST', 'UP', 'LOWER_UP'],
       'index': 3,
       'mac': '00:0c:29:41:fa:67',
       'name': 'ens34',
       'settings': {'group': 'default',
                    'master': 'br1',
                    'mtu': '1500',
                    'qdisc': 'pfifo_fast',
                    'qlen': '1000',
                    'state': 'UP'},
       'type': 'ethernet.physical'},
 'lo': {'flags': ['LOOPBACK', 'UP', 'LOWER_UP'],
    'index': 1,
    'inet': ['127.0.0.1/8'],
    'inet6': ['::1/128'],
    'name': 'lo',
    'settings': {'group': 'default',
                 'mtu': '65536',
                 'qdisc': 'noqueue',
                 'qlen': '1',
                 'state': 'UNKNOWN'},
    'type': 'loopback'},
 'vnet0': {'flags': ['BROADCAST', 'MULTICAST', 'UP', 'LOWER_UP'],
       'index': 8,
       'mac': 'fe:54:00:85:03:31',
       'name': 'vnet0',
       'settings': {'group': 'default',
                    'master': 'br1',
                    'mtu': '1500',
                    'qdisc': 'pfifo_fast',
                    'qlen': '1000',
                    'state': 'UNKNOWN'},
       'type': 'ethernet'}}

### get_ip_route() ###
{'default': {'dev': 'ens33', 'via': '192.168.1.1'}}

### get_all_interfaces_definition() ###
{'br1': {'enabled': True,
     'index': 4,
     'links': [{'address': '192.168.30.1/24', 'mode': 'static'}],
     'mac_address': '00:0c:29:41:fa:67',
     'monitored': False,
     'parents': ['ens34'],
     'source': 'ipaddr',
     'type': 'bridge'},
 'ens33': {'enabled': True,
       'index': 2,
       'links': [{'address': '192.168.1.55/24',
                  'gateway': '192.168.1.1',
                  'mode': 'static'}],
       'mac_address': '00:0c:29:41:fa:5d',
       'monitored': True,
       'parents': [],
       'source': 'ipaddr',
       'type': 'physical'},
 'ens34': {'enabled': True,
       'index': 3,
       'links': [],
       'mac_address': '00:0c:29:41:fa:67',
       'monitored': True,
       'parents': [],
       'source': 'ipaddr',
       'type': 'physical'}}
```

Here are some virsh diagnostics:

```
kurt@ZEUS-01:~$ virsh net-list
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes

kurt@ZEUS-01:~$ virsh  net-dumpxml default
<network connections='1'>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>4376d910-04a2-44f1-8f0a-440434bd66fd</uuid>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='br1'/>
</network>

kurt@ZEUS-01:~$ virsh iface-list
 Name                 State      MAC Address
---------------------------------------------------
 br1                  active     00:0c:29:41:fa:67
 ens33                active     00:0c:29:41:fa:5d
 lo                   active     00:00:00:00:00:00

kurt@ZEUS-01:~$ virsh net-info default
Name:           default
UUID:           4376d910-04a2-44f1-8f0a-440434bd66fd
Active:         yes
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      yes
Bridge:         br1
```

If I have missed any relevant diagnostic informaiton, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be my networking set up in Fusion.  I had my secondary network set up as NAT.  That was not going to work.  The problem was immediately solved by changing the interface to one of the host-only vnets.  I will route this vnet out one of the host bridged interfaces.

I hope this information helps someone save some time.